# Is there an OpenRasta like REST framework for Java?

Tags: java, rest, openrasta

The circumstances force me to start writing a java based server and I am looking for a REST framework for Java. I really like the way OpenRasta works - a REST framework for .NET, so my question - does anyone know a REST framework for Java which works similarly to OpenRasta?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, I am not in a position to be an early adaptor, so well established frameworks have preference over emerging ones.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use one of the implementations of the JAX-RS specification, one of the main ones being [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/). The specification and it's implementations have been around for a long time and are tried and tested (as opposed to Play! which you don't seem to like due to it being a newer framework).

I used OpenRasta and then worked on Java projects using JAX-RS. It will feel very familiar and you will get the benefits of POJOs like you get from OpenRasta's use of POCOs. I feel it's a great choice for creating RESTful services. In fact, I would probably chose it over OpenRasta now but this is more due the benefits of working within a Unix environment than the frameworks themselves.

Comment: Is Jersey resource centric, like OpenRasta?

Comment: Probably not to the same extent as OpenRasta but it's not difficult to use it in that way.

Answer (score 1):

The play framework is a popular new choice for Scala and the JVM:

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/routes

Answer (score 1):

One option is [Play!](http://www.playframework.org/), which is basically framework based off Ruby on Rails.

Second option you might be interested in is [Lift](http://liftweb.net/), which also has really cool features like comet, AJAXy snippets, etc. But it is a little bit different than Play!.

Answer (score 1):

As part of this project, I would recommend [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org) which is the first and most comprehensive REST framework for Java. It works on both client and server side and is indeed resource centric, not just a MVC framework adapted to REST.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I am evaluating it right now. Where can I post some of the questions I have about it?

Comment: You can post question in SOF, or more directly in our mailing list:
http://www.restlet.org/community/lists